# How to get all post/activity from google plus using c#

Tags: c#, google-plus

I am trying to get all the posts from google+ wall but I am able to get only 20 post. Kindly help me. My code is-

```
 PlusService plus = new PlusService(
            new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "AIzaSyDWG1Ho6PVC6FlPXv5rommyzCAf0ziHkTo"
            });

            ActivitiesResource ar = new ActivitiesResource(plus);

            ActivitiesResource.ListRequest list = ar.List(id, new ActivitiesResource.ListRequest.CollectionEnum());


            ActivityFeed feed = list.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `MaxResults` property of the `ListRequest` class.

```
PlusService plus = new PlusService(
            new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "AIzaSyDWG1Ho6PVC6FlPXv5rommyzCAf0ziHkTo"
            });

            ActivitiesResource ar = new ActivitiesResource(plus);

            ActivitiesResource.ListRequest list = ar.List(id, new ActivitiesResource.ListRequest.CollectionEnum());

            list.MaxResults = 100; // Or whatever number you want

            ActivityFeed feed = list.Execute();
```

Note that the maximum number is 100.

[Google.Apis.Orkut.v2.ActivitiesResource.ListRequest Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/orkut/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Orkut_1_1v2_1_1ActivitiesResource_1_1ListRequest.html#a173ec0b2fbaf1c7ca0dd349005fc157b)